# Set methods in a subclass

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to set values from the subclass by invoking the set method from the super class. I need to set monster name and health from the subclass

**Alien class**

```
public class Alien {
    //Instance variables
    public String monsterName;
    public int HP;
    //A method that sets monster properties
    public void setValues(String monsterN, int health) {
        monsterName = monsterN;
        HP = health;
    }
    //A method that returns the monster name
    public String getName() {
        return monsterName;
    }
    //A method that returns monster's health
    public int getHP() {
        return HP;
    }
    //ToString method that prints out the info
    public String toString() {
        return("Monster name: " + getName() + "Monster's current health  point: " + getHP());
    }
}
```

**Snake class**

```
public class SnakeAlien extends Alien {
    //Instance variable
    //Set the snake values
    Alien aObject = new Alien();
    aObject.setvalues("Snake\n" 55));
}
```

**The main class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Alien object = new Alien();
        object.toString();
        System.out.println(object);

    }

}
```

I know how would I set these values through the main class, but I need to do it from the sub class `SnakeAlien` which inherets from the `Alien` class.

Answer (score 0):

Because everything is public (which is terrible BTW) you can simply call the superclass' methods frimbthe subclasses. Not even super is needed.

Though, you **should** change members you don't want to reach from the outside to at least protected, and if you never want to make a pure Alien object, you should make that an avstract class.

Comment: I did not get the point. How can I call methods from a super class without object?

Comment: @TecHummer well, you have an object. In fact you're inside it. Imagine inherited functions as if they get concatenated to the subclasse's source code.

Comment: I still don't get it. How to use a method in sub-class which is from super class?

Comment: @TecHummer  Have you tried actually reading my comment? **The methods from the super class are basically in the sub-class, just use them**

Comment: Don't create a new Alien object